# How can I set the browser size in a Protractor Test

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

I'm looking for the Protractor to run in the maximum browser size before the actual tests start running.

I think you have to use a beforeAll() function, but not sure how to set the size? Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

The below code

```
var width = 200;
var height = 300;
browser.driver.manage().window().setSize(width, height);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
```

Comment: thanks, the problem was with the browser. This function call works fine on IE and firefox but not on Chrome

Answer (score 0):

If you're running on a virtual machine, sometimes the maximize() command doesn't do what you expect.

in protractor.conf.js `onPrepare`

```
var getScreenSize = function() {
    return browser.driver.executeScript(function() {
        return {
            width: window.screen.availWidth,
            height: window.screen.availHeight
        };
    });
};

getScreenSize.then(function(screenSize) {
    browser.driver.manage().window().setSize(screenSize.width, screenSize.height);
});
```